# Seemingly simple removal of trailing comma fails

Tags: r, regex

I have values with a comma before the numbers, like `‚0.10`. I want to remove the trailing `,` to get the number like `0.10`

I have tried `gsub(",", "", "‚0.10")`, but the comma is not removed. Any ideas what is going on here?

```
gsub(",", "", "‚0.10")
# [1] "‚0.10"
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some data to test.

Comment: It won't work if your column is a factor variable - try it with `gsub(",","", as.character(x))`

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why your replacement fails, despite it just "should work", is that there is a *control character* lurking around in `x`.

If I *copy-paste* both `pattern` and `x` from OP, the issue is reproduced:

```
gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = "", x = "‚0.10")
# [1] "‚0.10"
```

On the other hand, if I copy-paste `pattern` from OP, but *type* `x` in my editor, I get the desired result:

```
gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = "", x = ",0.10")
# [1] "0.10"
```

Thus, although the two calls *looks* identical, their results differ.

Then use `grepl` to look for control characters (`[:cntrl:]`):

```
# copy-paste x from OP
grepl(pattern = "[[:cntrl:]]", x = "‚0.10")
# [1] TRUE

# type in x in editor
> grepl(pattern = "[[:cntrl:]]", x = ",0.10")
# [1] FALSE
```

Indeed, there is something in the original `x` (and not in the `x` I type).

You may use `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode` to see what's hiding there. Again, copy-paste the string from OP:

```
library(stringi)
stri_unescape_unicode(str = "‚0.10") 
# [1] "\u00820.10"
```

Although the `,` in the original `"‚0.10"` looks like a [normal `,`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002c/index.htm), it is a [Unicode Character 'BREAK PERMITTED HERE' (U+0082)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0082/index.htm) comma which tricks us.

Thus, if this can't be fixed upstream, you may use:

```
gsub(pattern = "[[:cntrl:]]", replacement = "", x = "‚0.10")
# "0.10"
```